# Handling event listerners with changing dynamic classname on HTML element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have several dynamically generated HTML elements which each uses their own dynamic id as the class name. I have event listeners attached to those elements like this:

```
$(document).on("click", ".id_" + dynamic_id , clickCallback);
```

The problem is the dynamic id can change through an ajax success call, and the respective HTML element is updated like so:

```
$(".id_" + old_dynamic_id).attr("class", new_dynamic_id);
```

This change will make the previously attached event listener to be lost because it doesn't know that the HTML element now has a new id that was assigned.

What would be a clean way of handling this? I could re-attach the event listeners inside the ajax success function, but that is not ideal since there will be two places where the same event listener code will live: when creating the element and inside the ajax success function.

Comment: attach the event handlers to the elements themselves. currently, you attach the handler to the document, and use event delegation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
$(".link").on("click", function() {
    alert("yes");
});
$(".link").attr("class", "new-class");
```

I.e. if the event is attached to the element directly.

http://jsfiddle.net/5ru2W/

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
$(document).on("click", "[class^='id_']", clickCallback);
```